# accessing <td> value with selenium

Tags: java, javascript, html, xpath, selenium

Using selenium i'm trying to read out a dynamically generated table, i got down to the right elements (using the `findElement` method) but using `getText()` on them returns nothing.

Probably because `getText()` looks for quotation marks when returning "text" and can't find any between the `<td>` tags. Some suggestions were to use xpaths but since the tables are generated dynamically the location of the value i need also changes.

here's the table i'm trying to get 3 data points from:

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="fleetinfo">
        <tbody><tr>
            <th colspan="2">Schepen:</th>
        </tr>
                <tr>
            <td>Groot vrachtschip:</td>
            <td class="value">
                            40                        </td>
        </tr>
                <tr>
            <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="2">Lading:</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Metaal:</td>
            <td class="value">
                536.062            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Kristal:</td>
            <td class="value">
                289.008            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Deuterium:</td>
            <td class="value">
                92.750            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody></table>
```

the ones i'm interested in are the ones inside the `<td class="value">` tags but as i said before, using `getText()` on them returns null.

Any idea on how i can acces those values?

edit: here's how i'm doing it now

```
private int getMetalFromFleet(WebElement fleet)
    {
        int ret=0;

        WebElement streak = fleet.findElement(By.className("starStreak"));
        List<WebElement>fleetDetails = streak.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));

        for(WebElement detail : fleetDetails)
        {
            List<WebElement> tabel = detail.findElements(By.tagName("td")); 

            if(tabel.size() != 2)
                continue;

            if(tabel.get(0).getText().equalsIgnoreCase("metaal:"))
            {
                ret = Integer.parseInt(tabel.get(1).getText());
                break;
            }
        }

        return ret;
    }
```

edit: here's the relevant bit of html

```
<div id="fleet9965869" class="fleetDetails detailsOpened" data-mission-type="4" data-return-flight="false" data-arrival-time="1378241688">
        <span class="timer tooltip" title="03.09.2013 22:54:48" id="timer_9965869">58m 48s</span>
        <span class="absTime">22:54:48 Klok</span>
        <span class="mission neutral textBeefy">Plaatsen</span>
        <span class="allianceName"></span>
        <span class="originData">
            <span class="originCoords tooltip" title="killernerd"><a href="http://uni107.ogame.nl/game/index.php?page=galaxy&amp;galaxy=5&amp;system=213">[5:213:8]</a></span>
            <span class="originPlanet">
                <figure class="planetIcon planet tooltip js_hideTipOnMobile" title="planeet"></figure>k7                            </span>
        </span>
        <span class="marker01"></span>        
        <span class="marker02"></span>
        <span class="fleetDetailButton">
            <a href="#bl9965869" rel="bl9965869" title="Vlootdetails" class="tooltipRel tooltipClose fleet_icon_forward">
            </a>
        </span>
                <span class="reversal reversal_time" ref="9965869">
                <a class="icon_link tooltipHTML" href="http://uni107.ogame.nl/game/index.php?page=movement&amp;return=9965869" title="Roep terug:| 04.09.2013&lt;br&gt;01:54:05">
                    <img src="http://gf2.geo.gfsrv.net/cdna2/89624964d4b06356842188dba05b1b.gif" height="16" width="16">
                </a>
            </span>
            <span class="starStreak">
            <div style="position: relative;">
                <div class="origin fixed">
                    <img class="tooltipHTML" height="30" width="30" src="http://gf1.geo.gfsrv.net/cdnf0/af41c52dc08208b4463f4a4608e88c.png" title="" alt="">
                </div>

                <div class="route fixed">

                    <a href="#bl9965869" rel="bl9965869" title="Vlootdetails" class="tooltipRel tooltipClose basic2 fleet_icon_forward" id="route_9965869" style="margin-left: 220px;"></a>

                    <div style="display:none;" id="bl9965869">
                        <div class="htmlTooltip">
    <h1>Vlootdetails:</h1>
    <div class="splitLine"></div>
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="fleetinfo">
        <tbody><tr>
            <th colspan="2">Schepen:</th>
        </tr>
                <tr>
            <td>Groot vrachtschip:</td>
            <td class="value">
                            960                        </td>
        </tr>
                <tr>
            <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="2">Lading:</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Metaal:</td>
            <td class="value">
                8.173.484            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Kristal:</td>
            <td class="value">
                6.325.966            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Deuterium:</td>
            <td class="value">
                7.474.821            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody></table>
</div>                    </div>

                </div>

                <div class="destination fixed">
                    <img class="tooltipHTML" height="30" width="30" src="http://gf2.geo.gfsrv.net/cdnaa/af0b356fdbecc1cfc47130e990fa66.png" title="Aankomsttijd:| 03.09.2013&lt;br&gt;22:54:48" alt="">
                </div>
            </div>
        </span><!-- Starstreak -->
        <span class="destinationData">
                        <span class="destinationPlanet">
                <span>
                    <figure class="planetIcon planet tooltip js_hideTipOnMobile" title="planeet"></figure>Hoelbrak                                    </span>
            </span>

                            <span class="destinationCoords tooltip" title="killernerd"><a href="http://uni107.ogame.nl/game/index.php?page=galaxy&amp;galaxy=1&amp;system=2">[1:2:6]</a></span>

        </span>
        <span class="nextTimer tooltip" title="04.09.2013 03:52:31" id="timerNext_9965869">5u 56m 31s</span>
        <span class="nextabsTime">03:52:31 Klok</span>
        <span class="nextMission friendly textBeefy">Keer terug</span>
        <span class="openDetails">
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="openCloseDetails" data-mission-id="9965869" data-end-time="1378241688">
                <img src="http://gf3.geo.gfsrv.net/cdnb6/577565fadab7780b0997a76d0dca9b.gif" height="16" width="16">
            </a>
        </span>
    </div>
```

the values i need are the numeric values under "Metaal", "kristal" and "deuterium".

Comment: Yep, definitely need to see your current code

Comment: as requested i have updated the OP

Comment: I suspect the problem is the elements are not being selected properly when you create your lists. In Eclipse, you can use the debugger to check their value, or simply print them to the console like this:
`for(WebElement detail : fleetDetails)` 

        `{` 

             `System.out.println(detail)` 

        `};`
  
If the elements were selected properly, you'll see a bunch of hashcodes print out. But if there are no elements in the list, you won't see anything print out.

Comment: Maybe you thought that part was working because you didn't get any exception. But it doesn't throw any exception, because in Java, it's perfectly ok to have a list of length `0`.

Comment: well i thouroughly tested the code and if i use the ToString() method it prints what i expect it to print. Which is "<td class="value">", this tag should hold the value but getText returns null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found some kind of an answer after digging through a ton of programming sites.
Apparently items that have the `style="display:none";` flag set like this will be seen as "hidden" by selenium.

This is, unfortunately, a feature and not a bug of some sort as selenium "*tries to emulate the use*r" and will therefore hide information that is not explicitely visible.

"*The user can't see it so neither can selenium*" is their thought progress.

Here is the [source.](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=371#c4)

This, unfortunately, does not solve my issue. I can however try to get around this, I'll report back my findings.

**EDIT**: It's amusing how different HtmlUnitDriver is from FirefoxDriver. One thing that works on HtmlUnitDriver won't work on FirefoxDriver and vice versa.

**EDIT-2**: Found a solution! Finally.

Using selenium's `JavascriptExecutor` I can directly get the innerHTML from the found element like so:

```
By identifier = By.xpath("*[contains(@class,'starStreak')]//td[contains(text(),'Metaal:')]/following-sibling::td[contains(@class,'value')]");
    String script = "return arguments[0].innerHTML";
    String outcome = (String) ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript(script, fleet.findElement(identifier));
```

It's still annoying as hell that you can't just use `getText()` though. It should at least be an option.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using xpath in this scenario rather then relying on tagnames;

```
private int getMetalFromFleet(WebElement fleet)
    {
        By identifier = By.xpath("td[contains(text(),'Metaal')]/following-sibling::td[contains(@class,'value')]");

        return Integer.parseInt(fleet.findElement(identifier).getText());
    }
```

Obviously you will want some error handling in there, but hopefully this gives the idea that those loops are not always required, and Xpath isn't always the bogeyman it is made out to be by some.

EDIT

Just in case anyone is confused, it is okay for the XPath to not have leading slashes if the selector is performed on a WebElement rather than the WebDriver object.

You would have to add two leading slashes if this selector was used on the WebDriver object.

EDIT AGAIN!

Xpath may need some tweaking but you should get the idea of the approach.  I cannot see "StarStreek" in your html but it was in your code so added it  to my xpath.

Comment: Sorry, shouldn't have had the opening slash in the xpath

Comment: i didn't post more of the html because that would be a massive wall of code. Simply put starStreak is the surrounding tag that holds this table and other bits of information.

Wouldn't this also just return null? Since my issue wasn't about finding the object but about retrieving the value inside?

I'm not at all familiar with xpath's but i'll give it a shot anyway (copy-pasting yours gives a "cannot be evaluated" exception btw)

Comment: What returns"cannot be evaluated"? Try removing the reference to "starStreek".  Eg. Start xpath with "td"

Comment: Btw - I constructed the xpath in bed. Willbe able to try it later in the office

Comment: There was a typo in the xpath; I left the closing bracket off the td identifier.  I have also removed the "*[contains(@class,'starStreek')]".  Put this back if you have problems but I don't think you should need it

Comment: thanks for your responses so far and your xpath does work (it returns the right cell) but as i thought, calling 'getText()' on the found element returns null.

Comment: What if you do not perform the Integer Parse? Does it return text then? Also, are you sure you want to parse to integer? There are decimal places, integers don't have decimal places

Comment: Trying to print out the String comes up empty. And indeed, i'd have to remove the "points" inside the string before parsing but that doesn't matter (yet) since i get a NullPointerException anyway.

Comment: What does fleet.findElement(identifier).getAttribute("class") return?

Comment: it prints value as it should :P
So, as i said, i do get the correct cell it's just that i cannot retrieve the inner text/value using getText().

Comment: Try getAttribute("value")

Comment: it's just that selenium seemingly doesn't recognize text as a String if it isn't surrounded by double quotation marks.

edit: comes up empty.

Comment: WebDriver does not require string to be surrounded with quotation marks. I use getText() a lot in my projects and it works regardless of quotations.

If getText() does not work try `getAttribute("innerHTML");`

Comment: turns up null as well. If it isn't because of the quotation marks then i really don't understand why it won't work...

Comment: Can you get the entire page source via driver and post it here?

Comment: i could but that's alot of code. i'll post the relevant bit in the OP

Answer (score 0):

Got similar problem - i want to click on a row in a table which has given value. Solution (id can be changed to class name etc.):

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table[@id='<yourTableId>']//tr//td[contains(text(),'"+<givenValue>+"')]")).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

When I get value of td, I can get for 12 td per tr tag. More than 12 must one click on td tag then getText()
This work for me correctly.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).